# How different is the working of SNN (Spiking Neural Network) as compared to a real Neuron System in biological systems?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-networks, bioinformatics

Assuming its one step closer to realism as compared to ANN, DNNs and other Neural Network models, what are the primary differences between a real neuron system and SNN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different types of spiking neural network models:

- **Hodgkin-Huxley**: models the processes within a neuron with electrical parts. This results in differential equations with 4 variables (capacity of the membrane, resistance of the ion channels, balance potentials, openings of the ion channels).
- **Leaky integrate and Fire** (LIF): Probably the simplest SNN; it is only an ordinary first order differential equation
- **Spike Response Model**: models refraction time. It tries only to model the phenomena. Although it is simple, it is still more accurate than LIF.

I don't have a biology background, but I would say the Hodgkin-Huxley model is probably the closest to real neurons. However, as far as I know (which is very little), there is no (effective, plausible) **training algorithm**. So this is probably *the* key difference to the brain. Also the topology will certainly be different.

And, of course, we can model much less spiking neurons than we have natural neurons in a human. So the **number of neurons** is a key difference, too. I've heard SNNs have a few dozend neurons, probably up to several hundred neurons. The biggest MLP (CNN) models I've seen so far have about 150 000 neurons (see [Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385v1.pdf)). The human brain has about 86,000,000,000 neurons (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animals_by_number_of_neurons)).